# Converting a pandas dataframe to a class and saving using orm

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, orm

My code is working with a mixture of pandas dataframes and orm tables.  Because I wanted to speed up the retrieval of data using an index (as opposed to reading an entire file into a dataframe and re-writing it each time), I created a class statement to facilitate orm queries.  But I'm struggling to put it all together.

Here is my class statement:

```
engine_local = create_engine(Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI_LOCAL)
Base_local = declarative_base()
Base_local.metadata.create_all(engine_local)
Session_local = sessionmaker(bind=engine_local)
Session_local.configure(bind=engine_local)
session_local = Session_local()


class Clients(Base_local):
    __tablename__ = 'clients'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_year = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_cnt = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    date_posted = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    client_company = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    client_terr = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    client_credit = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    client_ann_prem = sa.Float(sa.Float)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Clients('{self.client_id}', '{self.client_year}', '{self.client_ann_prem}')"

meta = sa.MetaData()
meta.bind = engine_local
meta.drop_all(engine_local)
meta.create_all(engine_local)
```

And here is my panda definition statement:

```
    clients_df = pd.DataFrame(client_id, columns=feature_list)
    clients_df['client_year'] = client_year
    clients_df['client_cnt'] = client_cnt
    clients_df['client_company'] = client_company
    clients_df['client_terr'] = client_terr
    clients_df['client_credit'] = client_credit
    clients_df['client_ann_prem'] = client_ann_prem
```

I have an initialize step where I need to save this entire dataframe for the first time (so it will constitute the entire database and can write over any pre-existing data).  Later, however, I will want to import only a portion of the table based on client_year, and then append the updated dataframe to the existing table.

Questions I am struggling with:

1. Is it useful to define a class at all?  (I'm choosing this path since I believe orm is easier than raw SQL)
2. Will the pd.to_sql statement automatically match the dataframes to the class definitions?
3. If I want to create new versions of the table (e.g. for a threaded process), can i create inherited classes based upon Clients without having to go through an initialize step?  (e.g. a Clients01 and Clients02 table).

Thanks!

Comment: If you're already comfortable working with DataFrames then you could download a subset of the data via pandas' `read_sql_query()` method, manipulate the data in the DataFrame's rows (instead of individual ORM objects), and then write the updated values back to the database.